# What's the groupification of the cardinal numbers (without using AC)?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

The set-theoretic cardinal numbers form an abelian monoid under addition (ignoring size problems). Under the axiom of choice, given two cardinal numbers $c$ and $d$, there exists a cardinal number $e$ such that $c + e = d + e = e$. We now determine its groupification (or "Grothendieck group"): Considering formal differences, $c - d = (c + e) - (d + e) = e - e = 0$. So the groupification of the cardinal numbers is the trivial group.

What happens if we *don't* assume the Axiom of Choice? Things don't seem as easy because the cardinal numbers may only form a Partially Order Set (thanks to the CSB theorem). I don't know if they satisfy other properties in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even without the axiom of choice, $x+x\cdot\aleph_0=x\cdot\aleph_0$. In fact, $x+x=x$ if and only if $x\cdot\aleph_0=x$.

So, given any two sets $C$ and $D$, take $E=(C\cup D)\times\omega$. Then, let's denote the cardinals with the lowercase letters, we get that $c+e=d+e=e$.

Comment: Fun question, very clean answer.

Comment: A lot of the cardinal arithmetic "is there a larger cardinal" questions tend to have these kind of neat answers. It's real nice. It is also very frustrating, since it means that in a sense, cofinally often cardinal arithmetic is "nice", which can be a hindrance when you want to prove something implies AC.